# Firebase FCM not displaying on my iphone

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4, xcode9.2

Firebase FCM push notifications are not being displayed on my iPhone X. I have tried using firebase messaging 2.0.7 with FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0, 2.0.6, and 2.0.7 none have worked. I get the fcmtoken on the first app install and thats it. I am running ios 11.2.1 using swift 4 xcode 9.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.22, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
    attemptNotificationRegistration(application: application) }

override init() {
    super.init()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Registered for notif: ", deviceToken)
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    print("Registered with FCM with token:", fcmToken)

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}

private func attemptNotificationRegistration(application: UIApplication) {
    print("Attempting to register APNS...")

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
        if let error = error {
            alerts().errorAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, duration: 0)
            return
        }

        if granted {
            print("Auth granted.")
        } else {
            print("Auth denied")
        }
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by making a new xcode project and transferring my code and storyboards over. It looks like the issue was that I had previously had onesignal setup.